# count the number of values based on time period

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

context: I have a bus timetable dataframe - when a bus (`route_name`) arrives at the stop, the `number` column counts it

```
arrival_time        number  route_name
2022-04-06 05:35:00 1.0     A
2022-04-06 05:36:00
2022-04-06 05:37:00
2022-04-06 05:38:00
2022-04-06 05:39:00 1.0     B
2022-04-06 05:40:00
2022-04-06 05:41:00
2022-04-06 05:42:00
2022-04-06 05:43:00
2022-04-06 05:44:00
2022-04-06 05:45:00
2022-04-06 05:46:00
2022-04-06 05:47:00 1.0     B
2022-04-06 05:48:00 1.0     A
2022-04-06 05:49:00
2022-04-06 05:50:00
2022-04-06 05:51:00 
2022-04-06 05:52:00
2022-04-06 05:53:00 
2022-04-06 05:54:00 1.0     B
```

there are three bus routes that arrive at the stop and wait there until they complete the charge

routes and time for charge (min):

C: 13

B: 16

A: 11

what I need to get is the **number of buses and bus routes that are currently charging on the stop**. how do I get it?

The expected output (made manually):

```
arrival_time    number  route_name
2022-04-06 05:35:00 1.0 A
2022-04-06 05:36:00 1.0 A
2022-04-06 05:37:00 1.0 A
2022-04-06 05:38:00 1.0 A
2022-04-06 05:39:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:40:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:41:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:42:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:43:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:44:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:45:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:46:00 2.0 B, A
2022-04-06 05:47:00 2.0 B, B
2022-04-06 05:48:00 3.0 B, B, A
2022-04-06 05:49:00 3.0 B, B, A
```

Comment: It is still missing some data such as the dataframe of the buses, or a clearer explanation of the problem is needed

Comment: please go more into detail on how the logic is behind your desired output. As input you just showed one column with a datetime, isn't there more ? Where do you know when a bus stops somewhere? why the 2nd bus starts at `05:39:00`. why is the first route `T80` not in your output at all ?

Comment: added the missing data to the question. the second bus starts at ```05:39:00``` according to its timetable. the first route ```T80``` arrives only at ```06:52:00``` so I basically haven't made it that far

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to create a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) (implemented with a min-heap) and add to it a "leave" event with the time and bus route when you process a row of the dataframe. The time can be calculated as the arrival timestamp + the timedelta for charging.

At each iteration, you can check if the next bus arrives first or the current bus (if any) leaves first by comparing the next data row timestamp with the earliest leaving timestamp, the one on the top of the min-heap. If the leaving bus departs first, you can decrement the counter and pop from the priority queue. If the arrival happens first, you can increment the counter and insert into the queue, indexed by the time at which the bus will leave.

To get all the routes that are currently, you can simply iterate over the elements of the collection in linear time. Check the [Python heapq module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) for how an implementation of a priority-queue that is based on a simple list.

This is probably the easier to implement solution. Another possibility is to use a scanline-like algorithm where you use a single list for the arrive and leave events.